# Do something on key hold and on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to call function:

1. Every second when key is hold (e.g. for five seconds of holding it should fire 5 times every second).
2. When user releases key (`keyup`) and if less then one second passed.

Events should be binded on document, not on text input.

If second statement "kinda" works, with first I have problems as keypress event isn't working on some browsers and keydown fires event all the time.

```
var interval;
$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
    console.log('keypress');

    interval = setInterval(function() {
        doSomething(e.keyCode);
    }, 1000);

}).on('keyup', function(e) {
    console.log('keyup');

    if(interval === 0) {
        doSomething(e.keyCode);
    }
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = 0;
});


function doSomething(keyCode) {
     console.log(keyCode);
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kWFUA/

Thank you for help!

Comment: Change `keypress` to `keydown`: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kWFUA/3/

```
var interval;
var called = false;

$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    if(interval == null) {
        console.log('keydown');
        called = false;
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            doSomething(e.keyCode);
            called = true;
        }, 1000);
    }

}).on('keyup', function(e) {
    console.log('keyup');
    clearInterval(interval); 
    interval = null;
    if(!called)
        doSomething(e.keyCode);
});

function doSomething(keyCode) {
     console.log(keyCode);
}
```

Comment: Why do you use that `down` variable instead of just clearing the interval on-`keyup`?